# If X commutes with all elements of the Cartan subalgebra, then X is in the Cartan Subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple, complex Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ (defined to be the maximum abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing only ad-diagonalisable elements). Then we have:

If $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $[X,H]=0$ for all $H\in \mathfrak{h}$, then $X \in \mathfrak{h}$.

Can someone please help me out? Either by giving a proof or directing me to one, because I can't seem to find one anywhere. Thanks:)

(p.s. is the simple, complex part necessary for the result?)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question first: Neither "complex" nor "simple" are really necessary. One can relax the conditions and has the following statement:

> If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a (finite-dim.) semisimple Lie algebra over a field of
>   characteristic $0$, and $\mathfrak{h}$ is a subalgebra which is
>   maximal among those consisting of semisimple elements, then
>   $\mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{z}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak{h})$.
>
> Actually, one can show more, namely that $\mathfrak{h}$ is
>   self-normalising and nilpotent -- which is [another common definition for
>   Cartan subalgebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071417/96384). If one works over $\mathbb C$ or any algebraically closed field, one can replace "semisimple elements" in the above statement by "ad-diagonalisable", but in general one has to be careful about this, cf. my answer to linked question.

That those two definitions of Cartan subalgebras are equivalent is proposition 3.1.5 in [my thesis](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/algebres-de-lie-semi-simples-et-leur-classification-sur-les-corps-p-adiques), for which I combined ideas from Humphreys' book on Lie algebras with some from Seligman's "Rational Methods in Lie Algebras" and "A note on the centralizer ..."by Xiaoxi Xue. It is also exercise 3 to vol VII, §2 of Bourbaki's books on Lie groups and Lie algebras. The proof for the relevant part here goes like this:

Call $Z:=\mathfrak{z}_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak{h})$ that centraliser of $\mathfrak{h}$. First show that $Z$ is self-normalising, and that for each element $x$ it contains, it also contains its semisimple and nilpotent parts $x_s$ and $x_n$. (For these two facts, one only needs that $\mathfrak{h}$ consists of semisimple elements, not that it's maximal). Now by maximality it follows that every semisimple element of $Z$ must already be in $\mathfrak{h}$.

From this it follows that $Z$ is a nilpotent Lie algebra. Namely, if $x \in Z$, then we just noted that $x_s \in \mathfrak{h}$, hence the restriction of $ad(x)$ to $Z$ acts via the restriction of $ad(x_n)$, which is nilpotent, so all elements of $Z$ are $ad_Z$-nilpotent.

So we have shown that $Z$ is nilpotent and self-normalising, i.e. a Cartan subalgebra in the classical definition. But for those it's well-known (e.g. Bourbaki loc.cit. VII.2.4 Thm. 2) that all its elements are semisimple. But then the above implies that actually $Z=\mathfrak{h}$ all along, and we're done!

---

I admit that proof seems very indirect. I would be happy to see a more direct proof.