# Is requiring diagonalizable adjoints vacuous in the definition of Cartan subalgebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

One of the definitions of Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ one can find in the literature is that it is a

1. maximal abelian subalgebra
2. has the property that $ad_h$ is diagonalizable for all $h\in\mathfrak{h}$

I wonder whether, at least over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, the condition 2 is vacuous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not vacuous. Consider $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, $\mathfrak{h} = \Bbb C x$ for any non-semisimple element $x\in \mathfrak{g}$ (for example, $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$): It satisfies 1, but not 2, and is not a Cartan subalgebra.

Maybe it is noteworthy that a subalgebra which consists of $ad$-diagonalisable elements is automatically abelian (cf. Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*, section 8.1; see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4294819/96384)); so as long as you are over an algebraically closed field (of char. $0$), you can instead reduce the definition to "maximal with the property that all its elements are $ad$-diagonalisable".
But as soon as the ground field is not algebraically closed, so that the notions of "semisimple element" and "$ad$-diagonalisable element" become distinct, this can fail badly. It would still characterise maximal *split* toral subalgebras, but not maximal toral algebras, which are the Cartan subalgebras. For that distinction and examples, cf. my blunder in [Characterisation of Cartan subalgebras as maximal toral; redundant "abelian" in the definition of "toral"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/624932/96384), and the correct approach in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497093/96384.